# Print a calendar for 12 months

Tags: visualforce, javascript

[image]I have a visualforce page with a popular fullCalendar.js embedded in it and now I want to add print option so that the user can print calendar. I can use window.print() for a month but i m not getting how to print 12 months like we use in google calendar.

Comment: Could you please provide some screenshot depicting the issue you are struggling with?

Comment: This question probably belongs on [so].